# Simplify an expression with complex numbers

Tags: complex

How can I get a simplify expression of following when all a,b, .., f are real numbers?

```
FullSimplify[Abs[(a+I b)+(c+I d)(e+I f)]^2]
```

Comment: Use `ComplexExpand`.

Comment: Thanks @HenrikSchumacher

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

`PowerExpand` also works in this case:

```
FullSimplify[PowerExpand[Abs[(a + I b) + (c + I d) (e + I f)]^2], 
  Assumptions -> Element[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, Reals]]
```

> $(b+d e+c f)^2+(a+c e-d f)^2$

Answer (score 0):

```
FullSimplify@Assuming[{a, b, c, d, e, f} \[Element] Reals,
  ComplexExpand[Abs[(a + I b) + (c + I d) (e + I f)]^2]]
```

$a^2+2 a (c e-d f)+b^2+2 b (c f+d e)+\left(c^2+d^2\right) \left(e^2+f^2\right)$

Comment: By default, `ComplexExpand` will assume that all variables are real. Consequently, the simpler `FullSimplify@ComplexExpand[Abs[(a + I b) + (c + I d) (e + I f)]^2]` is equivalent to your proposed solution. Further, you will get the same result with `Simplify` in the place of `FullSimplify`